# Изменение расширения изображения в зависимости от браузера

Tags: javascript, html, css, изображения, браузер

Есть какой-то скрипт или что-то еще, например, если не загрузилась картинка с одним расширением в браузере, то загрузить такую же картинку с другим расширением?

Comment: Эм... Загружайте картинку в .jpg/.png, они работают всегда, делов то.

Comment: тут специфический случай, я работаю с расширение webp, не все браузеры его поддерживают.

Comment: по поводу webp можете почитать тут https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/webp

Comment: Я все-равно не понимаю. Если браузер не будет поддерживать webp то вы хотите загружать другой формат? Почему тогда сразу не загружать другой формать?

Comment: уже куча макулатуры прочитано по этому формату, но все равно спасибо.

Comment: нужна для всех браузеров поддержка, или предлагаешь с префиксами загружать?

Comment: https://github.com/FallingSnow/webp-polyfill

Answer (score 1):

Из большой книги CSS Макфарланда

> Несколько фоновых изображений кладутся стопкой друг на друга, как слои в программе редактирования изображений. Какое из них появится в верхнем слое, определяется порядком перечисления
>   фоновых изображений. Изображение, указанное первым, появляется в верхнем слое элемента,
>   второе — во втором слое и ....

Так можно попробовать через фоновые изображения CSS.
Что-то вроде:

```
background-image: url(MyImage.webp),
                  url(MyImage.png);
```

Но, здесь много нюансов, по поводу отображения, скорости загрузки, и т.д.
К тому же я не тестировал, просто предложил вариант для рассмотрения. Идея в том, что правило  `CSS` не распознанное браузером игнорируется и он использует другое правило при его наличии.

Comment: Вот по Вашему вопросу ещё информация, а именно атрибут srcset  в теге  <img> но опять же не проверял, поройте, возможно пригодится. https://webref.ru/html/img/srcset